# is nodejs createSign also working on deno?

Tags: deno

Is all node builtin modules working in deno? Is createSign which is a node method inside crypto working?

If not is there a way to do the same functionality as createSign with the current crypto standard library of deno?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is all node builtin modules working in deno? Is createSign which is a node method inside crypto working?

No, it's currently not implemented. See https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/da5b5d4688f03e578565966b1c0634a187f7729d/ext/node/polyfills/internal/crypto/sig.ts#L45

> If not is there a way to do the same functionality as createSign with the current crypto standard library of deno?

Yes, Deno uses Web Crypto API. You can use [`crypto.subtle.sign(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/sign)

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Web Crypto api. Marcos, how can I use this to sign some string using a .pem file? Thanks

Comment: Put the exact example you want with Node, and I can replicate the same in Deno, it'll depend what algorithm you're using and so on (Not all are yet supported)

Comment: hi Marcos, I have a private pem file and after reading it want to create a signature from nodejs createSign `const s = crypto.createSign('SHA512')` then create a base64 signature `s.sign({ key: privateKey}, 'base64')`.  I have this code working using node but I'm not sure how to convert this using web crypto. Thanks

Comment: Update: as of deno 1.33 majority of node crypto has been worked on, thanks to the Deno team. :D